# Firebase returns wrong values when addValueEventListener called

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database on Firebase and are trying to get android to print it into a ListView. I can get the ListView to print something, but it seems like it's some ID's of the values, rather than the actual values. The point is to be able to make a search bar, which can find any data on the database. 
I have some commented code down in the addValueEventListener. This code should work, but when I use it, my app crashes without an error when I go to the "ExistingCustomerActivity" activity. [My database structure and the output from the app, with the current code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghArB.png) Be aware the ListView currently prints the values just under "Buyers".
Is there anyone who can help with this issue? Thanks in advance.
Update: I can see the data are loaded correctly in the log, but it still displays some kind of ID I assume.

```
public class ExistingCustomerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
        private ListView mUserList;

        private ArrayList<Buyers> mUsernames = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_existing_customer);

            mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Buyers");

            mUserList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.UserListView);

            final ArrayAdapter<Buyers> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Buyers>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUsernames);

            mUserList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Buyers buyerList = new Buyers(childSnapshot);

                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) childSnapshot.getValue();
                        Log.v("YourValue,","Map value is:" +map.toString());
                        Buyers buyerList = new Buyers(map);
                        mUsernames.add(buyerList);

                    }
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Buyers class:

```
public class Buyers {
    private String car_Value;
    private String interest;
    private String driverLicenseNr;
    private String name;
    private String personNr;
    private String phone_Number;

public Buyers(Map<String,String> map){
    car_Value = map.get("Bil");
    interest = map.get("Interresse");
    driverLicenseNr = map.get("Kørekortnr");
    name = map.get("Navn");
    personNr = map.get("Personnr");
    phone_Number = map.get("Telefonnr");
}
```

Comment: there is no `PersonNumberTextField` inside your firebase DB structure

Comment: use actual variable name like `Bill,Intereresse and others` inside your `public Buyers()` constructor

Comment: The "PersonNumberTextField" is from another activity where I insert data to the database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your `Buyers` class variable according to firebase DB structure or use Map to get the values

Try below code to get values using Map from `Buyers`

```
mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //Buyers buyerList = new Buyers(childSnapshot);
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map<String,String> map=(Map<String, String>) childSnapshot.getValue();
            Buyers buyerList = new Buyers(map);
            mUsernames.add(buyerList);
        }
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Change your Constructor from `DataSnapshot` to `Map` and get the values and set into your local `Buyers` variable.

```
public class Buyers {
    private String car_Value;
    private String interest;
    private String driverLicenseNr;
    private String name;
    private String personNr;
    private String phone_Number;


    public Buyers(Map<String,String map){
       car_Value = map.get("Bil");
       interest = map.get("Interresse")
       driverLicenseNr = map.get("Korekortnr")
       name = map.get("Navn")
       personNr = map.get("Personnr")     
       phone_Number =map.get("Telefonnr")
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this code doesn't give any errors, but it still returns the values shown in the picture in the link in the description

Comment: did your change your `Buyers` constructor?

Comment: Yes, and it seems like that part works too, but the values are still those strings that I would assume are ID's for what I want

Comment: can you log or debug and check what is the value of map?

Comment: Don't know how to do that I'm afraid, very new to this

Comment: put this line `Log.v("YourValue,"Map value is: "+map.toString());`  after  `Map<String,String> map=(Map<String, String>) childSnapshot.getValue();` line

Comment: and run the app again and check logcat to see what is the value you are getting from firebase

Comment: It says something about the database was leaked. Can we move it to a chat?

Comment: @Michael you are using SQLLiteDatabase in your app close the DB after the use, and this is not the log we are looking for

Comment: @Michael post complete log after the `ExistingCustomerActivity` is launched

Comment: I've been trying most day and I know what you mean now. According to the log, the data are retrieved correctly. The log is several 100 lines long, so I can't post it here, can put it on pastebin tho if you still want to try and help :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like below.

```
    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //Buyers buyerList = new Buyers(childSnapshot);

                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            Buyers buyerList = childSnapshot.getValue(Buyers.class);
                            //buyerList = childSnapshot.child("PersonNumberTextField").getValue(Buyers.class);
                            //Buyers buyerList = childSnapshot.child("PersonNumberTextField").getValue(Buyers.class);
                            //Buyers buyerList = childSnapshot.getValue(Buyers.class);
                            mUsernames.add(buyerList);
                        }
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: `Buyers buyerList = childSnapshot.getValue(Buyers.class);` returns null record because in firebase variable and Buyers variable are different

Comment: then you have to do it same.

Comment: @akhilesh0707 is right, it makes the app crash, which is probably because it returns null. Do you got a way to solve this akhilesh0707?

Comment: yes either he can use a map or change the fields according to DB

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have the mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Buyers"); to go to the "Buyers" section, which I thought was enough to find the values of my DB

Comment: Not yet, but trying the second answer too, so far it doesn't give any error, but still show wrong values.